# How to cut till the last delimiter and get remaining part of a string

Tags: linux, bash

I have a path `./test/test1` and I need to extract the `test1` part.

I can do that with

```
cut -d '/' -f 3
```

But I may also have a path like `./test/test1/test1a` in which case I need to extract the `test1a` part.

I can do this in a similar manner by switching 2, 3, 4 to suit my needs.

But how can I achieve this if I have a list which contains some paths.

```
./test/test1
./test/test1/test1a/
./test/test1/test1a/example
```

How can I always make sure I extract the last part of the string after the last `/` delimiter? How do I start cutting from the last string up till the delimiter?

EDIT: Expected output:

```
test1
test1a
example
```

Comment: please update the question to show the expected output (corresponding to the provided sample inputs)

Comment: `man basename` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily cut after the last delimiter, using `awk`, as you can see here:

```
cat conf.conf.txt | awk -F "/" '{ print $NF}'
```

(For your information: `NF` in `awk` stands for "Number of Fields".)

However, as the second line ends with a slash, the second result will be empty, as you see here:

```
test1

example
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Thank you. I solved it with `rev | cut -d '/' -f1 | rev` but I guess this is  more elegant solution.

Comment: My solution is indeed more understandable: if you need to update your code within, let's say a year from now, you might understand my code, but not yours :-) Anyway, if you found my answer useful, please upvote and/or accept it, this is the way this site works.

Answer (score 0):

```
path=./foo/bar/baz

basename "$path"

# or pure shell:
echo "${path##*/}"
```

Both return `baz`. The counterpart, `dirname`, returns `./foo/bar`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what you mean by a "list".  Perhaps you have the paths in an array, or just a space separated string.  In either case, you can use `basename`, but the way you will use it depends on the data.  If you have a space separated string, you can just use:

```
$ cat a.sh
#!/bin/sh

list='./test/test1
./test/test1/test1a/
./test/test1/test1a/example'

basename -a $list
$ ./a.sh
test1
test1a
example
```

That form will fail if there are characters in IFS in any of the names.   If you have the names in an array, it is slightly easier to deal with that issue:

```
#!/bin/sh

list=('./test/with space/test1'
./test/test1/test1a/
./test/test1/test1a/example)

basename -a "${list[@]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean one-liner solution :

```
<<<"${test2}" mawk -F/ '$!_=$-_=$(NF-=_==$NF)' 

test1
test1a
example
```

Tested and confirmed working on `mawk-1.3.4`, `mawk 1.996`, `macos nawk`, and `gawk 5.1.1`,

including invocation flags of `-c/-P/-t/-S`

—- `The 4Chan Teller`